# Redirect log to specific log file by classname

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to redirect log to specific log file, by classname. The intention is to have a group of classes log output to a specific log file.

Right now the all output comes  to console, and  on startup it throws and error saying `log4j:ERROR Could not retrieve category [com.mycomp]. Reported error follows.`.

What am I doing wrong here?

In my java class :-

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SpringBootLog4jApplication.class.getName());
```

My log4j.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/' debug="false">

<appender name="LOGFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="/git/services.log"/>
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="20MB"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %x %p %c{1} :: %m\n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.mycomp" class="com.mycomp.SpringBootLog4jApplication" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LOGFILE"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the name for the logger should look like

```
<logger name="com.mycomp.*"...
```

as that would resolve to any concrete classes in the package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that did not help

Comment: Aw, Sorry. When I get home I'll have to look at how I have these things set up. and I'll try and find you a better answer :0)

Comment: No worries... I have got log4j2 working for now, but it will be nice to know how it would have worked in log4j